# Drupal Redirect User Login Page

Tags: redirection, users, .htaccess

Basically I need to redirect this page

```
http://website/?q=user 
to 
https://website/?q=user
```

I tried adding a redirect rule to the .htaccess file in /var/www/html/ but that didn't work. From what I know ?q=user is more of an argument then a page. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look a the [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) module, which is:

> A small process which will redirect the required pages to a SSL version of the page.

You can easily set up the `user/login` path as an SSL-required page, and the redirect will be handled for you.

If you want to do it manually, a rule like this in .htaccess would probably work:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^user$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/user [R=301,L]
```

That would need to go above Drupal's main rewrite rule for index.php.

It's worth bearing in mind you'll need to do this for the `user/login` path as well as that can be accessed directly.

Comment: Is there no other way to do a simple redirect? Plus I only need this one page to be SSL.

Comment: I've added an example rewrite rule, I haven't tested it but it should do the trick

Comment: I added that my .htaccess file and nothing changed. When I go to www.web.ca/?q=user there is no redirect.

Comment: It'll work if you've got clean urls turned on and you go to www.web.ca/user. If you're not using clean urls I can only really advise using the secure pages module; parsing a query string in .htaccess won't be a lot of fun

Comment: Question: If I enable clean URLs do I need to change all the internal links on the website? You know? References and such?

Comment: The `www.web.ca/?q=xyz` links will still work even if you've got clean urls turned on so you should be fine. If the site is public facing it might be a good idea to update the internal links if you can, it's better for SEO

Comment: The clean URL test failed. :(

Comment: Ah, that probably means your server isn't set up with mod_rewrite. It also means the .htaccess file won't even be processed so adding a rule in there isn't going to help I'm afraid; you'll have to attack this at the code level, either by installing secure pages or looking at the code and writing your own module that does something similar :/

Comment: That's intresting because my .htacces file actually does get processed. I added a number of rules in there regarding file permissions and they seem to have worked. I also use .htaccess in a number of other places in the site.

Comment: Sorry that was wrong, the .htaccess will still be processed but it looks like mod_rewrite isn't installed so you won't be able to use rewrite rules. The easiest way to test is to add any rewrite rule to the top of the file (outside of the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` condition). If your site suddenly dies with a 500 error, mod_rewrite isn't installed/configured correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Rules and make a rule that when going to that page to redirect the user to the https: page.

http://drupal.org/project/rules